# Parent page using wp_dropdown_pages and multiple post types

Tags: custom-post-types, page-attributes

Is there a way to get wp_dropdown_pages to return a list of multiple post types (including custom) as options for parent_id? I have tried supplying array for 'post_type' but beginning to think its either not possible? Or need to create a custom function to replace the meta box for page-attributes (parent_id) with a select which is built providing a list of multiple post type pages.

Ultimate aim is to allow CPT's to be moved around where a user wants them other than be restricted to the same post_type. Want to use differing post types for say example 'brand', 'model', so that if they wanted model to be under brand they could have /{brand}/{model}/ or if they wanted to attached model under a page such as 'special' be /special/{model}/. Don't want to have to just chuck everything under one post_type as thats probably counter productive and lazy.

Answer (score 1):

`wp_dropdown_pages()` does not accept a post type as an argument, however, [as noted in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages#Other_Parameters), it may be possible to use some arguments of `get_pages()` like `post_type`.

Unfortunately, the `post_type` argument for `get_pages()` [only accepts a string](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages#Parameters) and not an array of post types.

Although you may be able to pass a single post type as an argument to `wp_dropdown_pages()` you cannot pass an array of post types.

Comment: I was fearful that would be the response. Guess I am going to have to start thinking of another way.